# Javascript sharing JSON object across files

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON object declared in multiple files:

```
{
  filePath: this.filePath,
  fileSize: this.fileSize,
  fileDate: this.fileDate
}
```

Every time I make a change to the key names (e.g, filePath) I have to change it in multiple files which is very tedious. Is there a way to have this skeleton JSON somewhere and use/clone it in multiple files? The values for each key would be different in different files.

Comment: It depends on how you're using the JSON. You could always have a base JSON file, then another file for custom keys, etc.

Comment: If you're using Node you can just listen for changes to the file and update it when that occurs.

Comment: @ChrisHappy So when you have a base JSON file, and export it, do the keys get replaced? I would have to clone it right? Do you have an example?

Comment: No, I was thinking something different. Could you elaborate on why you need to change the keys? Because just like a house, if you change the keys, you need the change the locks as well.

Comment: @ChrisHappy The keys should be the same, the 'value' of the keys would change from file to file. I am basically doing a POST for each file to send out the JSON object with different values. I just don't want to declare the JSON object on top of each file in case we make key changes to the API (e.g, renaming). I would have to manually rename each file individually which is tedious..

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Solution**
If you must change the keys, I am thinking the best solution would be to use a PHP script that:

1. Reads each file
2. Loads the JSON
3. Changes the key name
4. Rewrites the file.

**Processing Solution**

You could also have a JSON file that maps keys.

For example:

```
{
   fooPath: filePath
}
```

Then when processing the JSON, use something like this:

```
GET mapped_keys
LOOP data
  LOOP mapped_keys AS key => value
    IF data HAS value
       data.key = data.value
    END IF
  END LOOP
END LOOP
```

So this:

```
{
  filePath: this.filePath,
  fileSize: this.fileSize,
  fileDate: this.fileDate
}
```

would become this:

```
{
  filePath: this.filePath,
  fileSize: this.fileSize,
  fileDate: this.fileDate,
  fooPath: this.filePath
}
```

But this is a hack.